# How do you get wheelspins in Forza Horizon 3?

Tags: forza-horizon-3

I noticed that you can get wheelspins, the game's equivalent of a gacha roll, every time you level up. I also noticed that you can get it at the end of a race. But what happens when you reach max level? What are the ways to get wheelspins?

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't receive spins from just completing races, you most likely were leveling up from the xp from that race and were awarded a spin.  Also, I am pretty sure that there is no max level as the highest I have seen on FH3 was 230-something.  If there are no max levels, then you would continue to level up and you would continue to receive wheelspins.

Answer (score 2):

In summary:

- The first way is to level up. Each level up will give you a wheel spin, up to Level 1000. After level 1000, every 200000 exp will give you another wheelspin.
- With the 'Spin It Again' perk in the Festival Boss Skill Tree, available for 5 perk points, you can purchase unlimited extra wheelspins for 50,000 CR a time. The VIP double credits bonus does not apply to these wheelspins.
- The perks Prize Time, Spinball Wizard, Lucky Hit, Fingers Crossed and Push Your Luck all give you 1 extra wheelspin. Once again, VIP double credit bonus does not apply.
- Some Forzathon events also give out bonus wheelspins for fulfilling certain conditions. For example, the latest Forzathorn (as of 16/11/2016) gave 3 wheelspins for doing 5 barrel rolls. The VIP double credits bonus does apply to these wheelspins.

The current best method of getting Wheelspins through leveling up is through this method:

At higher levels, if your only goal is to get wheelspins, you are much better off going for credits (by doing laps of Goliath with a Credits boost HE car) and purchasing wheelspins at 50,000 credits a time. For example, the above exp getting method results in around 7.5 wheelspins per hour. Doing 6 laps of Goliath (around an hours work) results in around 20 wheelspins.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to convert my comment into an answer as I played a good amount of F3H this weekend and confirmed that I didn't receive a wheelspin from just finishing a race.

You will receive a wheelspin anytime you level up. If you level up from the xp earned during a race, it will automatically spin for you. If you gain more than 1 level from the xp, you will only spin once.

If you level up in freeroam, you will be given the option to spin or it'll be kept for later under the 'Progress' tab.

Currently, it appears that there is no max level as the highest I have seen on FH3 was 280-something. If there are no max levels, then you would continue to level up and you would continue to receive wheelspins.

You also can receive a few additional wheelspins (limited) by unlocking the wheelspin bonus skill in the far right skill tree.

Answer (score 0):

After a certain point, I'm level 47 and it takes 5 to 6 levels before I get a wheel spin, also have noticed that when you complete a championship you can a free wheel spin also.

Answer (score 0):

you get a wheelspin everytime you level up ( every 20.000xp), if you reach max level (level 1000) you can still get a wheelspin every 20.000xp, if you are max level, it is indicated with a star instead of the number 1000. hope that helped you, for any more questions don't be scared to comment again

Answer (score -1):

You can unlock the skill in the skills tab: it lets you buy Wheelspins for 70,000.

Answer (score -3):

I am level 1000 or platinum as they say. The way it works is you need 93,585,000 exact XP to make level 1000 and after that you get a wheel spin every $200,000 XP. You don't get any extra money however ...my lifetime earnings when I made level 1000 was 580 million. I have every car in the game including every Horizon Edition and every single one of those is tuned and I have an excess of 30 million dollars so people that think they need a cash reward for making Platinum really shouldn't worry about it. Now I don't have to focus on leveling and racing as much and I can do the things I like like playground games more often.

Comment: This was already covered in more detail by an earlier answer